# How to click the button automatically with some action

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="ChoosePaymentOption();" class="calculate2" id="submitButtonId"/>
```

i want to click this automatically and onClick it should also run the function (ChoosePaymentOption();).
before this i have only the idea of this but it is not doing any action like not calling any function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to trigger click event on button and call the function within that.

```
$('#submitButtonId').click(function(){
   ChoosePaymentOption();
});
```

You can trigger that click on any point using `$('#submitButtonId').click();`